# UTC numbers to date/time

Tags: .net, date, sharepoint, utc

I got 130836384000000000 and I need to convert this number to date or date/time. The result should be 8/9/2015 7:00:00 PM. I can't figure this out with SharePoint workflow which uses .net framework. Any idea.  This formula works in excel
(130836384000000000/(8.64*10^11))-109205. I am using SharePoint designer and there isn't a way to run c# code using designer workflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime time = DateTime.FromFileTime(130836384000000000);
```

or

```
DateTime time = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(130836384000000000);
```

will return you the `DateTime` object from a timestamp. The first will be your local time, the second the Utc time, so you'll maybe need to add offsets dependent on the location.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. I don't think there is a way in SharePoint workflow (using SP designer) to invoke c# code. Can anyone confirm please? Thanks

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, as you didn't mention SharePoint Designer in your opening post, but said something about .NET framework.